# I want to add data below the last value of row a. (pygsheet)

Tags: pygsheets

sh[9].append(values=[claststr], start='a8')
This code adds a column.
I want to add a value to the next column with the last value of row 'a' or 'b'.[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
wks.append_table(["claststr", None, None, None])
```

Or you can use

```
 wks.update_value( (1,len(wks[0])), "classstr")
```

Comment: sh[9] .append_table (values ​​= [claststr], overwrite=True) 이코드를 이용해서 값을 추가할수 있었다.

Comment: However, this sometimes adds value to column A and sometimes to column D. I think we need to fix it in row A with dimensions in the option, but I don't know how to do it. Help me.